# Disable prefers-color-scheme: dark in django admin

Tags: django, google-chrome, django-admin, ckeditor, darkmode

I have dark mode enabled on Mac, but it looks awkward in django admin panel with ckeditor. Is it any option to disable it in Chrome or Django admin? I have already tried themes and browser extensions with no success.

[image]

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/

you can refer to the Django documentation and override the dark theme due to the your system settings (prefers-color-scheme)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're using some 3rd party theme for Django admin. I suggest checking if the maintainer of this theme wants to support Django 3.2 any time soon.

As for the quick fix for that, you can introduce your own stylesheet that will reset variables responsible for the dark theme. You can find the variables [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/base.css#L8-L92).

To achieve that, create a separate css file in your static file directory, copy over the `@media` declaration from the code fragment mentioned above and paste the normal color scheme inside it (also to be found in the same code fragment). After that, create a `admin/base_site.html` template, fill it with [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html) content or the equivalent from the theme you're using and link your custom CSS in the `extrastyle` block (you may need to create that block by hand).

Comment: There is a fresh new Django project. After installation admin panel was already dark. I decided to comment "@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)" section in /static/admin/css/base.css . Not sure that it's good solution but the fastest one.

Comment: I see you're using some wysiwyg editor and that's what is causing the troubles. Look for the new release of it to see if it supports dark color scheme. If not, see the issues list for this support and preferably report an issue if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @VictoriaSh That did not work for me. Any other solution ?

Comment: @ajinzrathod I've just commented `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {}` section in admin/css/base.css. That's the easiest way.

Comment: I can confirm that disabling the entirety of `django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/base.css` works. It'll disable the dark mode in Django's Admin, as of v 4.0.

Answer (score 8):

You can disable dark mode in Django 4.1 and above by overriding `admin/base.html` in your template. [https://github.com/django/django/pull/14929](https://github.com/django/django/pull/14929#pullrequestreview-775612264)

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% block dark-mode-vars %}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You have typo, should be `admin/base.html` instead of `admin/bash.html`.

Answer (score 6):

There's an app for that.

`pip install django-light`, details at https://github.com/frnhr/django-light.

Full disclosure: I'm the author. Well, more like "packager", not much original code there...

Comment: This worked almost instantly!

Answer (score 6):

as @GwynBleidD wrote, I changed my `admin/base_site.html` like this, and it works:

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}

{% block extrastyle %}
<style>
    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { 
        :root {
            --primary: #79aec8;
            --primary-fg: #fff;

            --body-fg: #333;
            --body-bg: #fff;
            --body-quiet-color: #666;
            --body-loud-color: #000;

            --breadcrumbs-fg: #c4dce8;
            --breadcrumbs-bg: var(--primary);

            --link-fg: #447e9b;
            --link-hover-color: #036;
            --link-selected-fg: #5b80b2;

            --hairline-color: #e8e8e8;
            --border-color: #ccc;

            --error-fg: #ba2121;

            --message-success-bg: #dfd;
            --message-warning-bg: #ffc;
            --message-error-bg: #ffefef;

            --darkened-bg: #f8f8f8; /* A bit darker than --body-bg */
            --selected-bg: #e4e4e4; /* E.g. selected table cells */
            --selected-row: #ffc;

            --close-button-bg: #888; /* Previously #bbb, contrast 1.92 */
            --close-button-hover-bg: #747474;
        }
    }
</style>
{% endblock %}
```