# disable dark mode in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, python-3.9, django-3.2

#### The Problem

I installed Django after couple of months. Current version is 3.2.4.

Earlier *Django-admin* was just **light-mode**. Current *Django-admin* switches automatically to **dark** or **light** according to system theme. Well, I do not want this behaviour. I want *Django-admin* to be **light theme** irrespective of system theme.
I am Not using 3rd party theme for *Django-admin*.

---

#### What I Tried?

As per one of the comment in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67194709/11605100) answer,

> I decided to comment "@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)" section in /static/admin/css/base.css . Not sure that it's good solution but the fastest one.

I tried commenting the code as shown here but does not work. I tried clearing cache and even tried switching browser but none of them seems to work. In browsers, I always prefer light theme. How can I achieve this? Any help is appreciable. Thanks in advance :)

---

#### System Details:

**OS:** Fedora 5.11.12-300.fc34.x86_64

**Python-Verion:** 3.9.5

Comment: You want to disable it for your own experience or the entire application users?

Comment: Actually, I wanna do it for everyone. But even if it solves only for me, that will work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st way:** The fastest way is to go to your OS Settings and change from your theme from *Dark* to *Light*. If you are using *Linux*, you might need `gnome-tweaks` to switch between themes.

---

**2nd way:**

1. Let us consider that you are using a virtual environment named
   **venv**. Now goto the following directory `venv/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/base.css`
2. **Comment** or **delete** all the code of `prefers-color-scheme: dark`. It would look something like this.

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
      /* code */
}
```

3. Now if you have also executed *python manage.py collectstatic* and
   let us assume that your static folder name is **static/**. Comment
   all the code of `prefers-color-scheme: dark` from the following file
   too: `/static/admin/css/base.css`

---

**Note:** Sometimes browser stores the CSS files in cache memory. To *hard reload* all the CSS files, *hard reload* the admin page using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

As of version 4.1 of Django, the proper solution seems to override a block in the `admin/site.html` template with empty content:

```
{% block dark-mode-vars %}{% endblock %}
```

This removes the dark-mode specific CSS links from the page.

Documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#theming-support).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately at the moment there is no feature toggle for disabling this behavior (django 3.2). in order only to have the light theme, you should delete the entire block of `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` code from `django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/base.css` file. or you can disable `prefers-color-scheme: dark` from your browser rendering options. instructions for chrome are described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59223868/9977321)

Comment: Deleting the entire block does not work. I have also written in question **I tried commenting the code as shown here but does not work.** I am firefox user. Anyways, thanks for this too :)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer only fixes it for the current user. A solution that would fix it for all users of the site would be similar, but would require copying base.css to your `static/css` directory and editing it there.

Alternatively (and this is what I did), just `pip install` [django-light](https://github.com/frnhr/django-light) and add it to your `INSTALLED_APPS` just before `django.contrib.admin`